# Jira REST APIs integration in reactjs application using "oath" authentication

Tags: reactjs, oauth, oauth-2.0, jira-rest-api

How to integrate jira's REST APIs in reactjs application using "oath" authentication.

Answer (score 0):

For a better understanding, you can start with this [documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-oauth-authentication/). For sample code, this [repo](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian_tutorial/atlassian-oauth-examples/src/default/) might be able to help you out; although there's no React specific sample, you can easily learn from the existing ones there (like Node.js) and apply it to your design as necessary.